# Create REST API in Rails 5 with only needed functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When I create a new REST API using the `--api` command in Rails 5 beta, it installs the `actioncable` and `sprockets` gems which I do not need.

How do I create the API without these gems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rails` command provides the `-S` option which skips the installation of the `sprockets-rails` gem.

The `rails` command for Rails 5 provides the `-C` option which, when used, skips the installation of *ActionCable* in the new app. It does not install the `redis` gem required by *ActionCable*. Because the [`actioncable` gem has been merged into `rails`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22586), the installation creates the files required for *ActionCable* but then removes them:

> remove  config/cable.yml
>   remove  app/assets/javascripts/cable.coffee
>   remove  app/channels

Both the `-S` and `-C` options can be combined in one command:

```
$ rails new rest-api --api -C -S
```